# Rename AccountController in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core MVC application, I would like to rename `AccountController` to something else ('Login', 'Authorization', does not matter the specific name).

But when I do this, the site still tries to route to `/Account/Login` even though there is no such thing. What do I need to do in order to stop this and have it use the right route?

I am setting `options.LoginPath` in `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie` but this does not seem to change things.

Here is my config setup:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Path = "/";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString($"/{nameof(Errors)}/{nameof(Errors.Access_Denied)}");
                options.ExpireTimeSpan= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);    // note: testing to see if this enforces logout based on minutes of idle time
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.LoginPath = new PathString($"/{nameof(Authorization.Authorization)}/{nameof(Authorization.Authorization.Login)}");
            });
```

Any suggestions? (Please ignore the nameof calls if they confuse you)

Comment: what kind of authentication are you using? if possible the related configuration code should be shared as well.

Comment: Custom authentication.  We can pretend that it accepts and username and password and always authenticates.  Or it would if it ever got to the auth screen.  If I change the name back to AccountController things will work.

Comment: I think the configured `LoginPath` works for cookie authentication only, if you have your own custom authentication, there is possibly some custom code to redirect the unauthenticated request to `/Account/Login`. If there is any configuration code, you should share it, if not try finding the hardcoded string `"/Account/Login"` in your solution code. It won't work if the code is in some referenced libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Core 3.1 project with custom auth, I specify `LoginPath` and `LogoutPath` like this in Startup#ConfigureServices:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = ...
                options.Cookie.Path = "/";
                options.LoginPath = "/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = ...;
            });
```

Comment: Thank you, setting those paths seemed to do the trick.  I hope this helps others who are trying to do the same.

Comment: @DanielWilliams: Nice :-) Please don't forget to close your question by accepting this answer. BR